# Vector visualization failed using plotters "required by a bound in `plotters::chart::ChartContext::<'a, DB, CT>::draw_series`"

Tags: plot, rust

I'm trying to visualize vector items in 2D using the crate "plotters".

```
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let file_path = "out.csv";
    let file = File::open(file_path);
    let mut rdr = csv::ReaderBuilder::new().delimiter(b',').from_path(file_path)?;
    let mut ke: Vec<f64> = Vec::new();  // reading itself is ok
    let mut pe: Vec<f64> = Vec::new();  // reading itself is ok

    for res in rdr.records() {
        let record = res?;

        ke.push(record[0].parse().unwrap());
        pe.push(record[1].parse().unwrap());
        println!("{:?}, {:?}", &record[0], &record[1]);
    }

    let (ke_min, ke_max) = ke.iter().fold((0.0/0.0, 0.0/0.0),|(m,n), v| (v.min(m), v.max(n)));

    let mut backend = BitMapBackend::new("outputs/test.png", (600, 400));
    let root:DrawingArea<_,_> = backend.into();
    root.fill(&RGBColor(255,255,255)).unwrap();
    
    let font = ("san-serif", 20);

    let mut chart: ChartContext<BitMapBackend, Cartesian2d<RangedCoordusize, RangedCoordf64>> = ChartBuilder::on(&root)
        .caption("kinetic energy and potential", font.into_font())
        .build_cartesian_2d(0..ke.len(), ke_min..ke_max)?;
    chart.configure_mesh().draw()?;
    chart.draw_series(LineSeries::new(ke, &RGBColor(255,0,0)));

    Ok(())
}
```

and the error is

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `for<'b> &'b DynElement<'static, plotters::prelude::BitMapBackend<'_>, f64>: PointCollection<'b, (usize, f64)>` is not satisfied
```

I`m a rustacean which was hatched from an egg a few seconds ago, so I'm not sure how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First split the line `chart.draw_series(LineSeries::new(ke, &RGBColor(255,0,0)));` into two lines:

```rust
let series = LineSeries::new(ke, &RGBColor(255, 0, 0));
chart.draw_series(series);
```

and look at the type of `series`: `LineSeries<BitMapBackend<RGBPixel>, f64>`.

If you look now at the error (some things simplified):

```rust
the trait bound DynElement<'static, BitMapBackend<'_>, f64>: PointCollection<'b, (usize, f64)> is not satisfied
```

You can find two parts: `<..., BitMapBackend..., f64>` looks *very* similar to the type of `series`. In fact that's the reason for the `f64` in the error message.

Now look at the type of `chart`:

```rust
ChartContext<BitMapBackend, Cartesian2d<RangedCoordusize, RangedCoordf64>>
```

Simplified you want to create a 2d coordinate system with x-values of type `usize` and y-values of type `f64`. These two types you can find also in the error message.

But now look: You want to create a *2d* coordinate system (x-values of type `usize`, y-values of type `f64`) but only supply an `Vec` of the y-values (of type `f64`) in `LineSeries::new`!
Probably you forgot your x-values!

If you look at [`LineSeries::new`](https://docs.rs/plotters/latest/plotters/prelude/struct.LineSeries.html#method.new) it takes a type which can be iterated to create the coords. So that would be in your case for your type of `chart` (you explicitly specified the type of `chart`) `IntoIterator<Item = (usize, f64)>`.

I don't know where the x-values will come from but if you don't really care you could try this, which will create a x-axis from 0 upwards.

```rust
chart.draw_series(LineSeries::new(
   ke.into_iter().enumerate(),
   &RGBColor(255, 0, 0),
));
```

If you want to customize the x-values, I recommend changing the type of `ke` to `Vec<(usize, f64)>` and create the appropriate values in your for-loop.

(It would be also helpful if you could include your `use`s, so that one can easily edit and test your code. Additionally stating the line of the error would be also helpful)

Comment: Thank you, Akida!!
Your answer solved my problem!